# How to access a variable from another class

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a class called currentUser and another called game. from game, i am trying to access a variable from currentUser, I know for sure that the variable is created and it contains something in currentUser before i call it in game but i get an empty string. What am i doing wrong here. here is what i have

```
public class currentUser
{
  private string currentUser;
  public string getCurrentUser
  {
    get {return currentUser;}
    set {currentUser = value;}
  }
  //this gets pushed in the beginning of the program
  private void btn_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    currentUser = txtUsername.Text;
  }
}

public class game
{
  currentUser myCurrentUser = new currentUser();
  string var = myCurrentUser.getCurrentUser();
  //this is another method being called in another class, but i dont think it is relevant. by the time i step over to here, var is null.
  clsScores.getScore(25, var);
}
```

i have tried looking, but this is the same example i see, so i don't know why it would not be working.

Comment: _it contains something_, no it really doesn't, with only these lines of code it will be `null`. Also, this won't compile.

Comment: so how do i get it to not be null?

Comment: add a constructor to currentUser to set the currentUser to some test variable to see if you are really assigning a value to currentUser. e.g. public currentUser() { currentUser = "test"; }

Comment: Edit the relevant code you think should work into your question, because this is not much to go on.

Comment: when i step over my program, i can see that there is a currentUser assigned.

Comment: Your class and property naming makes it a little confusing. The class "currentUser" is assigned, but its "currentUser" property isn't assigned in the code that you have shown us. Try my suggestion above and see if you get the "test" string instead of an empty string.

Comment: i know im sorry, i added more code that would be relevant

Comment: @failedprogramming maybe an example of how a get and setter is actually supposed to do? or how to make it so that i can access a variable from another class?

Comment: err.. i can't believe i missed this.... your statement: string var = myCurrentUser.getCurrentUser(); is incorrect. getCurrentUser is a property not a method, so you can drop the brackets. I also think var might be a reserved word. Maybe change it to: var user = myCurrentUser.getCurrentUser; Oops, i also just noticed your Game class doesn't look quite right either.

Comment: `var` is a sort of reserved word, but not completely. You can create a variable with the name var and the compiler will work out what you mean from the context, but it is best not to do that. The reason this happens is that the C# team took the view that since `var` is a recent addition to the language that code written in C#1,2, or 3 should all still compile in C# 4 (when the `var` keyword was introduced). It is best not to use `var` as the name of a variable, but if you want to disambiguate it you can add an `@` on the front, like you do when creating a variable called `class` --> `@class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: (I don't know how you are calling the code in Game, so I've just called it in a method DoSomething). If you get the result "No name", that means there's a problem with getting the user from the textbox.

```
public class CurrentUser
{
  private string _user;
  public string User
  {
    get { return _user; }
    set { _user = value; }
  }
  //this gets pushed in the beginning of the program
  private void btn_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtUsername.Text)
     {
         _user = "No name";
     }
     else
     {
         _user= txtUsername.Text;
     }
  }
}

public class Game
{
     public void DoSomething()
     {
         var myCurrentUser = new CurrentUser();
         var user = myCurrentUser.User;
         Console.WriteLine(user);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have accidentally put parenthesis in:

```
string var = myCurrentUser.getCurrentUser();
```

Remove them because "getCurrentUser" is a property, not a method. Properties do not need parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Ontop of a lot of other problems mentioned unless you are setting "currentUser" in the time between "currentUser myCurrentUser = new currentUser();" and "string var = myCurrentUser.getCurrentUser();". Your variable will never get set.